# sum function is returning wrong value

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables 
1.Franchiese

```
Id   Name
1    Vivek
```

2.Purchase

```
Id   Fran_id   commission_amount
1    1         100
2    1         1
```

3.Fran_payment

```
Id   Fran_id   amount
1    1         50
```

My SQL Query is

```
select franchiese.id,franchiese.name,sum(fran_payment.amount) as paid,sum(purchase.commission_amount) as tot,sum(purchase.commission_amount)-sum(fran_payment.amount) as rem from franchiese left join fran_payment on franchiese.id=fran_payment.fran_id left join purchase on franchiese.id=purchase.fran_id
```

It's giving me

```
Id   Name   Tot   Paid   Rem
1    vivek  101   100    1
```

Expected Answer

```
Id   Name   Tot   Paid   Rem
1    vivek  101   50     51
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two identical entries in the `Fran_payment` table.  Your SQL statement should work as intended, and is giving you logically correct values, but I think you have unexpected data in your table.

Comment: i have exactly same data as i had written in my question

Answer (score 0):

You are joining 3 tables which have unequal number of rows. Purchase table has 2 rows, while fran_payment has only one. At the time of join, the row in fran_payment is repeated to match the number of rows in purchase. Hence the row is duplicated and sum becomes 50 + 50 = 100 and your data would look like something like this-
ID | Name | fran_payment.amount | purchase.comission_amount
1  | Vivek   | 50                                   | 100
1  | Vivek   | 50                                   | 1

Try something like this

Select fran_id, sum(fran_payment.amount) as paid from purchase;

This should work.

Also, you'll need to run a sub query to only fetch data for given entry. Or, normal sum function would return the sum of while column, irrespective of the ID.

Select id, sum(fran_payment.amount from fran_payment where fran_payment.fran_id = id) as paid from franchise;

I hope that works. All the best.

PS: It's franchise, not franchiese.

Comment: It's giving me syntax error near from fran_payment in subquery

Comment: @vivekmodi it has been some time since I've worked with MySQL. Try sum(amount from fran_payment where fran_id = id).